# Relacionamento OneToMany para Classe com Composite PrimaryKey no Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho o seguinte relationamento[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na entidade de Definição Escala  tenho uma  `composite primary key` composta por **idEscalaDetalhe** e **idTurma**

Estou com dúvidas para fazer o mapeamento reverso entre EscalaDetalhes e Definicao escala utilizando hibernate pois e tenho uma classe @Embeddable  como primary key, como abaixo:

```
@Embeddable
public class EscalaDiaDetalhePK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mycolmumn")
    protected EscalaDetalhe escalaDia;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idTurma")
    protected Turma turma;

     //getters , setters , hash and equals
}
```

tenho a classe DefinicaoEscala :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "")
public class DefinicaoEscala {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EscalaDiaDetalhePKBean id;
    @ManyToOne  
    private Turno turno;
}
```

e quero fazer o reverso OneToMany para a entidade de definição, eu tentei da forma descrita abaixo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="ESCALADETALHE")
public class EscalaDetalhe{

   //properties
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER , mappedBy = "",orphanRemoval = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    public List<DefinicaoEscala> definicoes;


}
```

> O que eu deveria colocar no **mappedBy**?